# invalid literal for int() with base 9: 'TEXT'

Tags: python

```
import os
import random
name=input('what is your name? ')
print('hello lets answer some maths',name)
b=random.randint(1,10)
a=random.randint(1,10)
input(int("what is? ",float(b)+float(a) ))
```

Help 
i keep getting the error in the title although now it changes bases.

Comment: What this `input(int("what is? ",float(b)+float(a) ))` code will do ?

Comment: `int('what is?', float(b) + float(a))` will try to parse `what is?` as an integer with base `a+b` which seems to be `9` in your case, but will also fail for any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `int()` with a string *and* a base. The function signature looks like this:

```
int(x, base=10) -> int or long
```

So:

```
int("what is? ", float(b)+float(a))
```

tries to convert the string `'what is?'` to an integer, treating `'what is?'` as being in whatever random base `float(b) + float(a)` produces. Example:

```
>>> a = 8
>>> b = 1
>>> int('what is?', float(b)+float(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 9: 'what is?'
>>> b = 27
>>> int('what is?', float(b)+float(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 35: 'what is?'
```

What I think you are trying to do is simply output a prompt for user input, in which case you could change your code to:

```
answer = int(input("What is {} {} {}? ".format(float(b), '+', float(a))))
```

This uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create a formatted string with the two numeric values and the operator as arguments. The return value of `input()` is then converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling **int()** to perform on **string**

Pythonic way of iterating over a **file** and **converting** to **int**:

```
for line in open(fname):
   if line.strip():           # line contains eol character(s)
       n = int(line)          # assuming single integer on each line
```

The reason you had ValueError is because int cannot convert an empty string to the integer. In this case you'd need to either check the content of the string before conversion, or except an error:

```
try:
   int('')
except ValueError:
   pass      # or whatever
```

Comment: Not sure what iterating over a file has to do with this question.

Comment: No. This answer is way off. It has nothing to do with files, nor with empty strings. There is some merit, however, in handling exceptions - after all `int()` is being called on user supplied data.